# Computing gradient in Tensorflow vs PyTorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, gradient

I am trying to compute the gradient for a loss of a simple linear model. However, I face the problem that while using TensorFlow the gradient is computed as 'none'. Why is this happening and how to compute the gradient using TensorFlow?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = np.array([[73, 67, 43], 
                   [91, 88, 64], 
                   [87, 134, 58], 
                   [102, 43, 37], 
                   [69, 96, 70]], dtype='float32')

targets = np.array([[56, 70], 
                    [81, 101], 
                    [119, 133], 
                    [22, 37], 
                    [103, 119]], dtype='float32')

inputs = tf.convert_to_tensor(inputs)
targets = tf.convert_to_tensor(targets)

w = tf.random.normal(shape=(2, 3))
b = tf.random.normal(shape=(2,))
print(w, b)

def model(x):
  return tf.matmul(x, w, transpose_b = True) + b

def mse(t1, t2):
  diff = t1-t2
  return tf.reduce_sum(diff * diff) / tf.cast(tf.size(diff), 'float32')

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  pred = model(inputs)
  loss = mse(pred, targets)

print(tape.gradient(loss, [w, b]))
```

Here is the working code using PyTorch. The gradients are computed as expected.

```
import torch

inputs = np.array([[73, 67, 43], 
                   [91, 88, 64], 
                   [87, 134, 58], 
                   [102, 43, 37], 
                   [69, 96, 70]], dtype='float32')

targets = np.array([[56, 70], 
                    [81, 101], 
                    [119, 133], 
                    [22, 37], 
                    [103, 119]], dtype='float32')

inputs = torch.from_numpy(inputs)
targets = torch.from_numpy(targets)

w = torch.randn(2, 3, requires_grad = True)
b = torch.randn(2, requires_grad = True)

def model(x):
  return x @ w.t() + b

def mse(t1, t2):
  diff = t1 - t2
  return torch.sum(diff * diff) / diff.numel()

pred = model(inputs)
loss = mse(pred, targets)
loss.backward()

print(w.grad)
print(b.grad)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because in tensorflow, gradients are only computed for `tf.Variable`s. When you create a layer, TF automatically marks its weights and biases as a variable (unless you specify `trainable=False`).

So, in order to make your code work, all you need to do is wrap your `w` and `b` with `tf.Variable`

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=(2, 3)), name='w')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=(2,)), name='b')
```

Use these lines to define your weights and biases, and you will get actual values in your final print.